# Using Before keyword with method parameter in spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have entity Composition containing fields Date publicationDate and Boolean archival. I'm trying to get list of Compositions with publicationDate before date passed as argument and having archival flag set to false. After going through some of 'query creation from method names' tutorials and docs i came up with methods

```
List<Composition> findByPublicationDateBeforeDateAndArchivalFalse(Date date);
```

or

```
List<Composition> findByPublicationDateBeforeDateAndArchivalFalse(@Param("date")Date date);
```

but none of this works. Both gives UnsatisfiedDependencyException with

```
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property beforeDate found for type Date! Traversed path: Composition.publicationDate.
```

Intellij also underlines BeforeDate as it cannot resolve property beforeDate. What is the proper way of using those keywords with parameters so the parameters could be distinguished from fields by Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your method to following:

```
List<Composition> findByPublicationDateBeforeAndArchivalFalse(Date date);
```

`Before` keyword will compare `publicationDate` with `date` you pass as an argument, so there is no need to say `BeforeDate`. Just like an example in [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation):

`Before` -> `findByStartDateBefore` produces following SQL part `… where x.startDate < ?1`